Hyperbolic surfaces with only one short geodesic
$\textbf{Question}$: Let $R>0$. Does there exist a compact hyperbolic surface $S$ which has one and $\underline{only\ one}$ primitive geodesic of length $\le R$?
I am aware of the fact that the number of closed geodesics of length $\le R$ has to be finite and that there are upper bounds for such a number on a generic surface, but I am specifically interested in an example where this number is one.
Also, I am specifically interested in geodesics, not geodesic loops.
$\textbf{Attempt}$: For who is familiar with Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates, I am thinking of an example of the following kind. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\ge R$, and let $S$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $n$ with Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates
$$L=\left(\frac{1}{n},\underbrace{n,\dots,n}_{3n-2}\right),$$
$$A=(\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{3n-3}).$$
I think that the $\underline{only}$ primitive geodesic on $S$ with length $\le R$ is the parameter geodesic of length $\frac{1}{n}$, but I am not able to prove or disprove this statement.

Can you clarify the meaning of a "primitive" geodesic? I can think of two possibilities: a simple closed geodesic; or a closed geodesic that is not obtained by going two or more times around a shorter closed geodesic.

Sure: By a primitive geodesic I mean a closed geodesic which cannot be obtained as a power (or concatenation) of two or more other closed geodesics. That is, according with the second possibility stated above, a closed geodesic that is not obtained by going two or more times around a shorter geodesic.

You should specify if you are fixing the genus ahead of time or not. If not, then the answer is positive (for every $R>0$ there exists $S$).

I am not fixing the genus. In my attempt indeed the genus depends on $R$ as I want the surface $S$ to have genus $n\ge R$.

I will add a proof later on then.

This is a partial answer which only covers the case that $R$ is sufficiently small.
In that case the answer to your question is yes. However the construction you suggest does not work for the following reasons. Let's fix a pants decomposition of the surface, which fixes a choice of Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates. If you choose a large $n$, make one pants curve have length $1/n$, and make all the others have length $n$, then the trouble is that each pair of pants whose pants curves all have length $n$ looks more like a string bikini with long strings: any two of its pants curves are a very, very tiny distance apart. Also, in the one pair of pants with one short curve of length $1/n$ and two long curves of length $n$, those two long curves are a very, very tiny distance apart. If you line up the twist parameters then you can get a very, very short transverse curve (even shorter than $1/n$).
Nonetheless, with more care you can do this (if $R$ is sufficiently small). Choose $\epsilon$ to be at least as small as the Margulis constant. The Margulis Lemma tells us that every primitive geodesic of length $\le \epsilon$ is simple, and any two such geodesics are disjoint. Choose one pants curve to have length $\epsilon$, and the others to have length $1$ (I picked that rather "large" length out of a hat). In each pair of pants, the distance between two pants curves has a positive lower bound which one can compute with a bit of hyperbolic trigonometry. A similar lower bound holds in each pants incident to the one short pants curve, for the distance between its other two boundary components. The set of closed geodesics which are not one of the pants curves therefore has a positive lower bound $B>0$ independent of $n$. Choosing $\epsilon$ smaller than the minimum of $B$ and the Margulis constant and you are done.
When $R$ is large then the problem is quite different because one loses the topological control given by the Margulis lemma. I do not know a simple solution in that case, although by the very fact of the discreteness of the spectrum it seems quite likely.
